# coldfusion "String index out of range" error with argumentcollection

Tags: coldfusion

I'm passing form variables in a cfinvoke argument collection:

```
<cfinvoke component="#application.componentPath#.account" method="updateServices" argumentcollection="#form#" />
```

But I keep getting the error: "String index out of range: 0 null"
I've narrowed it down to something to do with the form variables passed in the argumentcollection. When I do a `<cfdump var="#form#">`, it looks like this:

```
form - struct

EMAIL_1 wendy 
EMAIL_2 [empty string] 
EMAIL_3 [empty string] 
EMAIL_4 [empty string] 
FIELDNAMES EMAIL_1,EMAIL_2,EMAIL_3,EMAIL_4,
```

(I can't do a screenshot of the struct so you'll have to imagine it.)

If I lose the argumentcollection from the cfinvoke, the error disappears.

The receiving CFC:

```
<cffunction name="updateServices" access="public" output="true" returntype="void">

     <!--- deliberately emptied to see if it was anything inside the cfc causing the issue--->

</cffunction>
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't see what's going on in your component, so this is a guess. When you use `argumentcollection` with `<cfinvoke>` and pass in a struct, the struct is broken out in the component as if its elements had been passed in as individual arguments. So if you have:

```
<cfset foo.this = 1>
<cfset foo.that = 2>

<cfinvoke...argumentcollection="#foo#">
```

...then inside the component you'll have:

```
arguments.this; // 1
arguments.that; // 2
```

You will not have `arguments.foo.this`, nor `foo.this`. So if you want to pass in your form scope and have it encapsulated inside the component, you can try this:

```
<cfinvoke...formscope="#form#">
```

Then, inside the invoked component method, you'd be able to use:

```
arguments.formscope.EMAIL_1
arguments.formscope.EMAIL_2
arguments.formscope.FIELDNAMES
```

...etc. You might also look into `<cfinvokeargument>`. If none of this helps, maybe posting a bit of what happens inside the component will shed further light.

Comment: Thanks, the formscope one did the trick, but I had to reference it in the cfc with ARGUMENTS.formscope.EMAIL_1, as opposed to just formscope.EMAIL_1, which the function didn't recognise.

Comment: Yes, you're right -- `formscope` in the example above becomes a member of the arguments scope; it's been updated. Glad you were able to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that might be wrong is:

> ```
> component="#application.componentPath#.account"
> ```

Try hard-coding that to a cfc path that you know exists (com.whatever.account), and if it then works, then you know what was causing the problem (the dynamic component expression).